# Aligning three inline elements to left, middle and right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a floating bottom menu that will work for multiple screen resultions. So far I was unable to make the three independent elemnts align in left, middle and right positions.

Here is what it should look like on a wide screen:

[image: Wide screen]

On a mobile screen (worst case scenario):

[image: On mobile screen]

On a mobile screen (best case scenario):

[image: No mobile screen]

Here is the JSFiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYw6a/

I tried using: `display: inline-block;` on children and different combinations of alignment on parent and children. It only made the toolbar look like starcase. Setting `height: 0;` did not help much either. Even though everything was inline, resizing caused items overlapping.

I had this wild idea of using a table.. I don't event want to try. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell` to display your divs like table cells:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Div with text Buttons</div>
    <div class="middle">Div with span Image sprite</div>
    <div class="right">Div with textarea Search field</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .left, 
.container .middle, 
.container .right {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}
.container .left {
    color: #9AD0E5;
    background: #3F48CC;
    width: 200px;
}
.container .middle {
    color: #3F48CC;
    background: #FF7F27;
}
.container .right {
    color: #A349A4;
    background: #880015;
    width: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .container .left, 
    .container .middle, 
    .container .right {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B3Wp8/1/)**